# Controle sidebar angularJS

Tags: angularjs, menu, sidebar

Bom dia pessoal. Sou novo no fórum e no mundo da programação web. Fiz alguns cursos de AngularJs estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro aplicativo e surgiu uma dúvida quanto ao código que estou utilizando. Preciso que o siderbar(navbar) seja recolhido sempre que acontecer um clique no menu.Segue abaixo o código:

```
<a href class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
</a>
<div class="navbar-custom-menu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown messages-menu" ng-include="'/template/header/navbar/messages.html'"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar(com angularJs)? Muito obrigado.

Comment: <a href class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
</a>
<div class="navbar-custom-menu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown messages-menu" ng-include="'/template/header/navbar/messages.html'"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

Comment: Boris, edite a sua pergunta e coloque o código que está no comentário na pergunta para ficar mais legível e fácil de entender. Você está usando Boostrap? Se for, qual versão?

Comment: Ola Ricardo obrigado pelas dicas. Sim estou, usando a Bootstrap v3.3.7 e AngularJS v1.6.6